How do I use flex to have a div aligned to the left spanning all the height, two divs to the right aligned to top and bottom within a background div?
So I have 4 divs, one of which is the parent acting as a "background" div, and 3 other divs inside of that one. I want to align the larger one to the left and have it span the full height of the div. I want to align the two smaller ones to the right with the first one on top and the second one on bottom. How could I achieve this with flex?
This is what I want:

This is the code I currently have:


.brown {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  height: 170px;
  background: brown;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
}

.green {
  background: green;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
}
<div class="brown">
  <div class="yellow">
    <div class="green">
      <div class="blue">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



I am also using bootstrap so if I could do this with only bootstrap util classes that would be awesome.
Thanks in advance!

SO much easier with Grid. Why insist on Flexbox?

Suggestion
The layout you want is as follows if you use the bootstrap.
There are many other methods.
Method1
using grid


.brown {
  width: 300px;
  height: 170px;
  background: brown;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas: 
    "yellow . blue"
    "yellow . ."
    "yellow . green";
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  width: 190px;
  height: 100%;
  grid-area: yellow;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  grid-area: green;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  grid-area: blue;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>HTML + CSS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="brown">
    <div class="yellow"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



Method2
using flex, align content


.brown {
  width: 300px;
  height: 170px;
  background: brown;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  width: 190px;
  height: 100%;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>HTML + CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="brown d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div class="yellow"></div>
      <div class="right d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
        <div class="blue"></div>
        <div class="green"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



Method3
using flex, margin, flex-grow


.brown {
  width: 300px;
  height: 170px;
  background: brown;
}

.yellow {
  background: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 55px;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 55px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>HTML + CSS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="brown d-flex">
    <div class="yellow me-2"></div>
    <div class="right d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="blue"></div>
      <div class="space flex-grow-1"></div>
      <div class="green"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>



